# Method works correctly when called from within its class but not otherwise

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, instantiation

I wrote this function in my `RootViewController`. `appRecord` is an object holding an XML attribute.

```
- (NSString*) getString:(int)row{
    AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *appName = appRecord.appName;

    return appName;
}
```

I want to use this function again by writing this:

```
RootViewController *record = [RootViewController new]; 
NSString *appsName = [record getString:0];

NSLOG(appsName);
```

After I compiled, it didn't return anything, but it works and returns `appsName` if I use this function inside the `RootViewController` class (`[self getString:0]`), so I know there is no problem with the function. When I tried to change `return appName` to `return @"test"`, it worked and returned something when I accessed it from the other class.

This means there is a problem with this `appRecord`; it was returned inside the class but returns nothing when I access it from another class.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps there is nothing in your `RootViewController`? What does the `new` message do?

Comment: When is `self.entries` created i.e. filled?

Comment: @Yann [`new`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/new) is short for `alloc` + `init`.

Comment: kids these days with their shortcuts *shakes fist*

Comment: @Jesse: `new` is actually the old-fogey way -- it was NeXTSTEP's preferred creation method; Cocoa prefers the two-step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting your AppRecord from `self.entries` *in* the instance of RootViewController `record`.  This means unless your `new` initializer initializes and populates its `entries` variable (array by the looks of things) before you call `getString:`, it won't be able to return anything since that array is empty.

Beyond that, I don't know if you want your `getString:(int)` method to access a different array, or if the problem is in your initialization of `RootViewController` (more likely)

Comment: Since new just calls the init method... maybe that's the issue. Don't view controllers get instantiated by initWithNibName:bundle: and not just init?

Comment: @Nick Bradley - depends on whether you declare an `init` function as the default initialiser, and have that call the superclass with the desired nib name

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but if you are relying on the NSLog statement to see if the function is returning anything, you should change it to:

```
NSLog(@"%@", appsname);
```